# How to filter in mongodb asp net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

```
public class Employee
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("Titles")]
    public List<EmployeeTitle> Titles { get; set; }
}
public class EmployeeTitle
    {
        [BsonElement("DepartmentCode")]
        public string DepartmentCode { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("JobTitleCode")]
        public string JobTitleCode { get; set; }
    }
```

How to filter [Employee.Titles.DepartmentCode] in list  departmentCodes ?

My code :

```
var query = Builders<Employee>.Filter.In(employee => employee.Titles.DepartmentCode, departmentCodes);
```

But running error " 'List' does not contain a definition for 'DepartmentCode' and no accessible extension method 'DepartmentCode' accepting a first argument of type 'List' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) ".

Please help me ! Thanks all

Comment: ***what*** error?

Comment: List<EmployeeTitle>' does not contain a definition for 'DepartmentCode' and no accessible extension method 'DepartmentCode' accepting a first argument of type 'List<EmployeeTitle>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

ElemMatch can help, but it is not for array of department codes.

```
builder.ElemMatch(employee => employee.Titles, t => t.DepartmentCode == "Code1");
```

I am not sure but you can try this as well

```
builder.ElemMatch(employee => employee.Titles, t => departmentCodes.Contains(t.DepartmentCode));
```

Answer (score 0):

This can help you, as it did for me.

```
var query =  Builders<Employee>.Filter.Eq(employee=> employee.Titles.DepartmentCode, departmentCodes);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).